# reason for crashing of the windows

Tags: windows, crash

I wrote some program which uses information about (reads via Windows)  hardware of the current PC (big program, so I can't post here code) and sometimes my windows 7 crashes, the worst thing is that I have no idea why, and debug doesn't help me, is there any way to receive from windows 7 some kind of log, why it crashed? thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct (but somewhat ugly) answer:

Go to Computer->Properties, go to 'Advanced System Settings'.
Under startup and recovery, make sure it is set to "Kernel memory dump" and note the location of the dump file (on a completely default install, you are looking at C:\windows\memory.dmp)

You optimally want to install Windows Debugging tools (now in the Windows SDK) as well as setting the MS Symbol store in your symbol settings (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff552208(v=vs.85).aspx)

Once youv'e done all that, wait for a crash and inspect memory.dmp in the debugger.   Usually you will not see the exact crash because your driver vendors don't include symbols, but you will also generally get to see the DLL name that is involved in the crash, which should point you to what driver you are dealing with.

If you are not seeing a specific driver DLL name in the stack, it often indicates to me a hardware failure (like memory or overhead) that needs to be addressed.

MS has a good article here at technet that describes what I mentioned above (but step by step and in greater detail) http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2008/11/01/how-to-debug-kernel-mode-blue-screen-crashes-for-beginners.aspx

You can also look at the event log as someone else noted, but generally the information there is next to useless, beyond the actual kernel message (which can sometimes vaguely indicate whether the problem is driver or something else)